# Javascript alert and prompt functions does not work when site installed as WebAPK

Tags: javascript, android

This very basic code don't show any prompt / alert when executed in a webpage executed as [WebAPK](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks) (website installed as app by clicking the "add to homescreen" button) :

```js
document.write('1');
alert('My Alert');
document.write('2');
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="prompt('Answer me please')">Show me prompt</a>
```

Why ?

Note: there is no problem with the "confirm" function which show the message as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a Chrome bug, because since the update of the app (with version 69.0.3497.91) there is no problem anymore.